# Javascript Outputs Not Changing?

Tags: javascript

The code below always results in...

career = "A Veterinarian!";

highField = "animal";

I'm confused why this is happening. If someone could find any problems with the code or explain what is happening it would be greatly appreciated.

```
var career = "An ERROR!";
var highField = "ERROR";
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

if ((Math.max(getNumber("animalsSlide"), getNumber("mathSlide"), getNumber("cookingSlide"), getNumber("biologySlide"), getNumber("performingSlide"), getNumber("writingSlide"), getNumber("creativeSlide"), getNumber("inventingSlide"))) == getNumber("animalsSlide")) {
  career = "A Veterinarian!";
  highField = "animal";
} else if ((Math.max(getNumber("animalsSlide"), getNumber("mathSlide"), getNumber("cookingSlide"), getNumber("biologySlide"), getNumber("performingSlide"), getNumber("writingSlide"), getNumber("creativeSlide"), getNumber("inventingSlide"))) == getNumber("mathSlide")) {
  career = "An Engineer!";
  if (x < 2) {
    career = "An Accountant!";
  } else if (x == 4) {
    career = "A Doctor";
  }
  highField = "math";
} else if ((Math.max(getNumber("animalsSlide"), getNumber("mathSlide"), getNumber("cookingSlide"), getNumber("biologySlide"), getNumber("performingSlide"), getNumber("writingSlide"), getNumber("creativeSlide"), getNumber("inventingSlide"))) == getNumber("cookingSlide")) {
  career = "A Chef!";
  highField = "coooking";
} else if ((Math.max(getNumber("animalsSlide"), getNumber("mathSlide"), getNumber("cookingSlide"), getNumber("biologySlide"), getNumber("performingSlide"), getNumber("writingSlide"), getNumber("creativeSlide"), getNumber("inventingSlide"))) == getNumber("biologySlide")) {
  career = "A Doctor!";
  if (x == 4) {
    career = "A Veterinarian!";
  }
  highField = "biology";
} else if ((Math.max(getNumber("animalsSlide"), getNumber("mathSlide"), getNumber("cookingSlide"), getNumber("biologySlide"), getNumber("performingSlide"), getNumber("writingSlide"), getNumber("creativeSlide"), getNumber("inventingSlide"))) == getNumber("performingSlide")) {
  career = "An Actor!";
  highField = "performing";
} else if ((Math.max(getNumber("animalsSlide"), getNumber("mathSlide"), getNumber("cookingSlide"), getNumber("biologySlide"), getNumber("performingSlide"), getNumber("writingSlide"), getNumber("creativeSlide"), getNumber("inventingSlide"))) == getNumber("writingSlide")) {
  career = "An Author!";
  highField = "writing";
} else if ((Math.max(getNumber("animalsSlide"), getNumber("mathSlide"), getNumber("cookingSlide"), getNumber("biologySlide"), getNumber("performingSlide"), getNumber("writingSlide"), getNumber("creativeSlide"), getNumber("inventingSlide"))) == getNumber("creativeSlide")) {
  career = "An Artist!";
  if (x < 2) {
    career = "An Actor!";
  } else if (x == 4) {
    career = "A Chef!";
  }
  highField = "creative art";
} else if ((Math.max(getNumber("animalsSlide"), getNumber("mathSlide"), getNumber("cookingSlide"), getNumber("biologySlide"), getNumber("performingSlide"), getNumber("writingSlide"), getNumber("creativeSlide"), getNumber("inventingSlide"))) == getNumber("inventingSlide")) {
  career = "An Engineer!";
  if (x < 2) {
    career = "An Artist!";
  }
  highField = "inventing";
}
```

Comment: It's happening because your first `if` condition is being met. Why would you expect it to change from one run to the next?

Comment: This is a great time to start using a debugger.  (Your browser most likely comes with one.)  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line and observe its behavior.  When you do this, which specific operation produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: @Marc I understand how if statements work, but I'm still getting the same results when the first condition isn't met.

Comment: You must not be supplying all of your code, because you appear to only ever evaluate that tree of `if/else` statements one time. Also, have you verified that the "first condition isn't met" in your debugger as @David recommends?  I think you'll find that you're mistaken.